# why are we using relative scheme // instead of http:// or https://?

Tags: html, http

I've been having lots of problems with this new trend. It's been included everywhere (e.g. htmlboilerplate / twitter widgets) yet even twitter itself doesn't like it... (see image, when trying its twitter card preview).

[image]

Is there more to this than meets the eye, as it seems this has been implemented by coders before its been utilized fully by browsers or is it a legacy html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because many sites are offering both regular (http) and encrypted versions (https) and using sub-domains for various things like images. you'd have to produce two completely different versions of the site if you were embedding things like

```
<img src="http://images.example.com/kittens.jpg" />
```

and served that up on the `https://` version of the site, even though it's the exact same content. No one likes getting SSL errors, especially since those tend to come up as "zomg you're being spoofed/hacked/defrauded" type warnings in browsers.

But if you have the protocol-relative version,

```
<img src="//images.example.com/kittens.jpg" />
```

it won't matter if you're accessing the site via http://, https://, or even ftp:// for that matter - the url will still work and use the appropriate protocol, and you only have to maintain one copy of the content.

Comment: but it doesnt run locally which is a massive drag :(

Comment: @benbyford If you have a hostname in there it won't work locally anyway.

Comment: thats true, ill get back to you, its seems that everytime i try using it (html5 boilerplate for example) it fails to load. I'll investigate and get back to you

Comment: just had a think and it doesnt explain why twitter is having problems with it as per image above..?

Comment: maybe twitter's parser doesn't support protocol-relative addressing. if you add a full `http://...` protocol in, does it start working?

Comment: yep, fine with http:// in the card preview but... in its own widget it uses // in the <script> soo... thats silly